# Conda: Pip upgrade corrupted pip, how to get back pip in the env

Tags: python, pip, conda

I upgraded pip using:

```
> pip install --upgrade pip

Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: 'commands'
```

Now it is using the system's pip from `/usr`

**How do I get back pip in my conda environment?** (perhaps without reinstalling the env)

I tried after activating the environment

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

but that just gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

for python2

```
    sudo python -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python-pip --reinstall
```

for python3

```
    sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
```